# Query double sort

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of items and which supplier they came from: tabel `items`

```
Ttem ID - Item Title - Supplier - Date added
```

A supplier may supply multiple items, neither the title nor the supplier are unique.

I want to show the latest added 56 items, and, from those 56 items I want to show the top ten suppliers

So individually I have:

```
select * 
from items 
order by dateadded desc 
limit 56
```

And for the suppliers

```
select count(supplier) as howmany 
from items 
group by supplier 
order by howmany desc 
limit 10
```

My question is how to show the top ten suppliers of the 56 items selected

Thanks for any help

Comment: @MahmoudGamal, that won't work, because the `order by` is processed after the `group by`.

Comment: @dan1111 Correct - tried that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just combine your two statements and use the first one as a subselect:

```
select count(*) as howmany from (
    select * from items order by dateadded desc limit 56
) top_items group by supplier order by howmany desc limit 10
```

**Update:** You originally had `count(supplier)`, which should work, but is not as clear as it could be (it sort of looks like you are trying to count the number of suppliers).  I changed to `count(*)` to highlight the fact that you are counting the rows (number of items) for each supplier.

Comment: I get error: Every derived table must have it's own alias - ??

Comment: Based on what I have read, a limit should be supported on this type of subquery in MySQL.  Let me know if it is not working.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney, updated with an alias.  Sorry, I don't use MySQL specifically.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the top 10 suppliers of the most recent 56 items:

```
SELECT COUNT(supplier) AS howmany
FROM items

WHERE item_id IN (
    SELECT t2.item_id
    FROM items t2
    ORDER BY t2.dateadded DESC
    LIMIT 56
)

GROUP BY supplier
ORDER BY howmany DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't support limit in sub queries apparently